# System-level energy/power preferences

Tags: permissions, power-management, users, preferences

In Windows, mmc allows to set energy/power preferences for all users at a system-level: they can't change these settings until an administrator unlocks them.

Is there any way to do the same in ubuntu?

(I know I can customize those settings in /etc/skel + locking down permisisons of power management binaries and user preferences: is there a more elegant and not so tricky solution?)